# Writing a persistent perl script

Tags: linux, perl, bash, unix

I am trying to write a persistent/cached script. The code would look something like this:

```
...
Memoize('process_fille');
print process_file($ARGV[0]);
...
sub process_file{
    my $filename = shift;
    my ($a, $b, $c) = extract_values_from_file($filename);
    if (exists $my_hash{$a}{$b}{$c}){
        return $my_hash{$a}{$b}{$c};
    }
    return $default;
}
```

Which would be called from a shell script in a loop as follows

```
value=`perl my_script.pl`;
```

Is there a way I could call this script in such a way that it will keep its state. from call to call. Lets assume that both initializing '%my_hash' and calling extract_values_from_file is an expensive operation.

Thanks

Comment: IMO this depends on how frequently the script is used.  If it is just run every now and then, use a serialization technique. If it is more than that -- eg, it is serving some kind of crucial perhaps real time relative purpose -- make it a persistent background server/use IPC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If %my_hash in your example have moderate size in its final initialized state, you can simply use one of serialization modules like [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable-2.30/Storable.pm), [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-2.32/XS.pm) or [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.131/Dumper.pm) to keep your data in pre-assembled form between runs. Generate a new file when it is absent and just reload ready content from there when it is present.

Also, you've mentioned that you would call this script in loops. A good strategy would be to not call script right away inside the loop, but build a queue of arguments instead and then pass all of them to script after the loop in single execution. Script would set up its environment and then loop over arguments doing its easy work without need to redo setup steps for each of them.

Answer (score 15):

This is kind of dark magic, but you can store state after your script's `__DATA__` token and persist it.

```
use Data::Dumper; # or JSON, YAML, or any other data serializer
package MyPackage;
my $DATA_ptr;
our $state;
INIT {
    $DATA_ptr = tell DATA;
    $state = eval join "", <DATA>;
}

...
manipulate $MyPackage::state in this and other scripts
...

END {
    open DATA, '+<', $0;   # $0 is the name of this script
    seek DATA, $DATA_ptr, 0;
    print DATA Data::Dumper::Dumper($state);
    truncate DATA, tell DATA;  # in case new data is shorter than old data
    close DATA;
}
__DATA__
$VAR1 = {
    'foo' => 123,
    'bar' => 42,
    ...
}
```

In the `INIT` block, store the position of the beginning of your file's `__DATA__` section and deserialize your state. In the `END` block, you reserialize the current state and overwrite the `__DATA__` section of your script. Of course, the user running the script needs to have write permission on the script.

Edited to use `INIT` block instead of `BEGIN` block -- the `DATA` block is not set up during the compile phase.

Comment: Serialize state - yes. Rewrite it inside yourself - big damn NO! This might look funky and yield a +1 or two, but it is a complete mess to maintain.

Comment: Very cool, but seems unhealthy to print to your actual source code file.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the script to keep state. As soon as the process exists any information not written to disk is gone.

There are a few ways you can accomplish this though:

- Write a daemon which listens on a network or unix socket. The daemon can populate `my_hash` and answer questions sent from a very simple `my_script.pl`. It'd only have to open a connection to the daemon, send the question and return an answer.
- Create an efficient look-up file format. If you need the information often it'll probably stay in the VFS cache anyway.
- Set up a shared memory region. The first time your scripts starts you save the information there, then re-use it later. That might be tricky from a Perl script though.

Answer (score 0):

No. Not directly but can be achieved by very many ways.

```
1) I understand **extract_values_from_file()** parses given file returning hash.
2) 1 can be made as a script, then dump the parsed hash using **Data::Dumper** into file.
3) When running my_script.pl, ensure that file generated by 2 is later than of the config file. Can achieve this via **make**
3.1) **use** the file generated by 2 to retrieve values.
```

The same can be achieved via freeze/thaw