# Write to the Data Section in Perl

Tags: perl

It is quite easy to read from the data section `__DATA__` in Perl.
The following code uses the preexisting `DATA` handle:

```
foreach (<DATA>) {
    print("- $_");
}

__DATA__
1
2
The End of The End
```

produces:

```
- 1
- 2
- The End of The End
```

However I haven't found any neat way of writing data to the section.
For example I've tried the following:

```
use feature say;

say STDERR 'Some Error';
say STDOUT 'Some Message';
say DATA   'Some Data';

__DATA__
foo bar
```

The print to `STDOUT` and `STDERR` works as expected:

```
perl write.pl 2> /dev/null 
Some Message
```

But the print to `DATA` does nothing at all:

```
tail -2 write.pl 
__DATA__
foo bar
```

I also have looked at several modules from CPAN, but I always only found support for *read*, not *write*.
Thanks for any hints and help!

Comment: It is a really, really bad idea to modify a Perl script from within the script. Use a separate data file instead.

Comment: It may be a bad idea, but it (maybe, couldn't test it until now) can be handy for some fancy gimmick tools. I'm looking for a sane way of doing it (if any sane way exists). The insane way would probably be to open a filehandle on the own script... if this is even possible?

Comment: You cannot 'write' to the DATA filehandle. You can "open" `$0` - and seek/write to it. But this is not a good idea.

Comment: There is now a showcase for this supposedly bad idea on CPAN: https://metacpan.org/release/App-Unding

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write to the DATA section with a text editor.

Everything else is [dark magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353338/168657). Store input and program state in a separate file (or a database).

Comment: In this case I don't mind Dark Magic! I'll check this as soon as possible. Thx for the hint. If it works as intended, an actual answer with implementation would be neat.

Comment: @BorisDäppen *You* may not mind dark magic, but whoever has to maintain your software after you will mind it very much.

Comment: @BorisDäppen Someday, someone will probably want to rant at you for going with such a solution, and that someone will probably be you. On the other hand ... [it's a really cool solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQm5BnhTBEQ).

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good thing to "copy and paste" the code here instead of just linking?

Comment: Actually it might be a better thing to erase the link.

Comment: There is now a module on CPAN, using this "dark magic". I'll make the case, that in this case, it's fine, despite all the warnings: https://metacpan.org/release/App-Unding

Answer (score 3):

There is probably no good reason to this, but here is how:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

seek DATA, 0, 2; # go to the end of the source file
my $offset = tell(DATA); # remember where that is

open my $f, '>>', $0 # open source file for appending
    or die $!;       # of course, you could use DATA instead of $f here

seek $f, $offset, 0; # go to the previously recorded position

print $f "This is a test\n"; # put something there

__DATA__
```

Comment: This solution is always appending at the end of the file. I'm looking also how to replace the data. I think with your solution and the "dark magic" from mob I will be able to do what I want. Thanks for this helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to add things to what DATA can output, you can close it, then reopen it on a reference to a variable containing additional text, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
    print("- $_");
}

close DATA;

my $additional_text = 'test2';
open DATA, '<', \$additional_text;
$additional_text .= "\ntest3";
while(<DATA>) {
    print("- $_");
}

__DATA__
test
```

But you need to use the originally data contained in the DATA section before, I think.

Comment: As far as I understand, this is not persistent in the file. Maybe I'm not clear enough in the question regarding this. But I'm looking for something persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to DATA would change the script. This is a bad idea because DATA is open for read on the script itself. This program illustrates why this is a bad idea.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

seek DATA, 0, 0;
while( <DATA> ){
    print;
}

__DATA__
1
2
3
```

Comment: By running your script, it's not obvious to me, what exactly the "why" is, that you are referring to and trying to show with the script. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: The DATA file handle is open for read on the whole script. You can reopen it for writing and then change the entire script. This leaves it vulnerable to code injection.