# In Perl, why can't you use __DATA__ as a seekable filehandle?

Tags: perl, seek

Reading from DATA via the typical  slurp works. Trying to use DATA as a filehandle on which I can do a seek does not work. Is anyone able to point me the to the obvious mistake I must be making?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

if ($ARGV[0] eq 'seek' ) {
    my $log_fh = \*DATA;
    $log_fh->seek(64,0);
    print "\n-- 64 --\n",join ("", <$log_fh> );
} else {
    while (<DATA>) {
        print $_;
    }
}

exit;

__DATA__
01234567890123456789
1234567890123456789
1234567890123456789
12
X <- That X is the 64th char in
this file.
Y <- That Y is the 106th char in this file.
junk
more junk.
bye!

$ perl file_from_data.pl slurp
01234567890123456789
1234567890123456789
1234567890123456789
12
X <- That X is the 64th char in
this file.
Y <- That Y is the 106th char in this file.
junk
more junk.
bye!
```

Running the while() loop:

```
$ perl file_from_data.pl slurp
01234567890123456789
1234567890123456789
1234567890123456789
12
X <- That X is the 64th char in
this file.
Y <- That Y is the 106th char in this file.
junk
more junk.
bye!
```

Running the seek(), it appears to not start at **DATA** but the start of the script:

```
$ perl file_from_data.pl seek

-- 64 --
'seek' ) {
    my $log_fh = \*DATA;
    $log_fh->seek(64,0);
    print "\n-- 64 --\n",join ("", <$log_fh> );
} else {
    while (<DATA>) {
        print $_;
    }
}

exit;

__DATA__
01234567890123456789
1234567890123456789
1234567890123456789
12
X <- That X is the 64th char in
this file.
Y <- That Y is the 106th char in this file.
junk
more junk.
bye!
```

This is an old Perl:

```
$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux- 
thread-multi
```

Comment: [`DATA` is seekable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353338/168657). Store the result of `tell(DATA)` when the script starts and treat that as the first byte of the `DATA` stream.

Comment: Avoid DATA if you need it seekable; use a separate file instead.  Is this for a module you are distributing?

Comment: For what it's worth, take a look at https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Section::Simple. Not exactly what you describe you want to do, but maybe useful anyway.

Comment: @simbabque - I will keep this in my League of Extraordinary CPAN Modules. :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

> Running the seek(), it appears to not start at **DATA** but the start of the script

I don't think you're making any mistake at all. That's exactly what happens. `DATA` is a filehandle that is open on your source file. Before your first `read()` from that filehandle, the file pointer is positioned immediately after the `__DATA__` token in the file. But you can use `seek()` to move the file pointer to any position at all in the file.

I guess it would be harder to implement a "special case" filehandle that wasn't able to move back before its initial position.

Comment: OP can just use SEEK_CUR (instead of SEEK_SET) as the whence.

Comment: Duh - special semantics. So I should while() until __DATA__, get that position, then all seeks are relative to that.

Sounds like something that is either on CPAN or should be.

Thank you.

Comment: The other thing to do is:

`my $log_fh = \*main::DATA;
my $whence = $log_fh->tell();
$log_fh->seek($whence + 64,0);
print "\n-- 64 --\n",join ("", <$log_fh> );`

Comment: @mpersico, Don't search for `__DATA__`. You're already positioned there. Use `SEEK_CUR` to move forwards 64 bytes.  If you need to seek back to the start, use `tell` to note the start position (before doing any seeking or reading)

Comment: @ikegami - look up to the third comment. :-)

Comment: Don't use magical numbers like that. Use `SEEK_CUR` from Fcntl